# How to add Puppy Linux to grub menu installed by Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, system-installation, dual-boot, grub2, puppy-linux

I've been using Puppy Linux off a USB flash drive drive for a while, but that was really wearing it out. I decided to do a full install to the hard drive, so I cleared out some space, created an ext4 partition, and installed.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to add it to the Grub menu that Ubuntu installed. I looked around the documentation for a while, then decided that, rather than risk screwing something up, I'd just ask for help.

The output of `fdisk -l` is:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19452 cylinders, total 312500000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf475f475

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   196527491    98263714+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       196528126   312498175    57985025    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       308310016   312498175     2094080   82  Linux swap
/dev/sda6       196528128   295727103    49599488   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       295729152   308307967     6289408   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 4004 MB, 4004511744 bytes
255 heads, 32 sectors/track, 958 cylinders, total 7821312 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32     7817279     3908624    b  W95 FAT32
#
```

I have a Windows XP installation on `sda1`, an Ubuntu installation on `sda6`, and I've installed Puppy Linux on `sda7`. (Currently, I'm running Puppy Linux off of `sdb1`.) I'm not sure where Grub is, but I think it's either on `sda6`, with Ubuntu, or hiding somewhere in `sda`'s MBR. Not sure though.

Basically, I need to find out how to add an entry to the Grub boot screen, with these options:

```
title Puppy Linux 5.4
root (hd0,6)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda7 pmedia=atahd
```

I've already tried to puzzle it out, but I couldn't manage to pull it off. I just need step-by-step instructions. I will provide any other config files or Terminal outputs requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you currently using GRUB2 you can simple run this command:

```
update-grub                            # it's an ubuntu alias for following command
# or
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg   # it'll work on all distributions that uses GRUB2
```

This update automatically grub entries.

Comment: Neither of those commands exist on Puppy Linux (I just tried both of them 12 seconds ago,) and if I run them on Ubuntu, how will it know the correct options to run Puppy Linux (or even that Puppy Linux exists on my hard drive?)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude it will probe all the other partitions on the machine, looking for OSes to boot. Give it a try from Ubuntu and see if it works.

Comment: Exact what @derobert commented, you need run one these commands in Ubuntu, and it's automatically check installed OS and add for GRUB2 menu (ubuntu)

Comment: remember that "update-grub" is an alias, and it's only added in Ubuntu and baseds...
for example, if you running ArchLinux, you need use second command

Comment: okay, `sudo update-grub` got it working. It generated three new menu entries: `unknown Linux distribution (on /dev/sda7)`, `unknown Linux distribution (on /dev/sda7)`, and `Puppy Linux'. The first launches Puppy Linux, the second is identical to the first, and the third one (the one labeled "Puppy Linux") is broken. How do I remove the last entries from the menu?

Comment: you can manually edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg and remove these entries

Entries start with "menuentry [...] {" and end with "}"